# How to plot Time Interval only on x axis without date?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using R-3.2.4.
I have been trying to plot the data with only time on x axis and some value on y axis but everytime it shows some date on along with time on x axis, however i need only time interval on x axis.

Here is the code that i am using:

```
data_plot<-        read.csv("C:/.../Data_pract.csv",header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=F)
data_plot$Time<-as.POSIXct(strptime(data_plot$Time, format="%H:%M"))
mydata<-ggplot(data_plot,aes(x=Time,y=January))+geom_line()
mydata
```

Here is the sample data that i am using:

```
    Time January
    0:00    20
    0:15    30
    0:30    45
    0:45    40
    1:00    28
    1:15    15
```

I have attached image of graph that i am looking for.

Thanks in advance.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5QxFW.png)

Comment: Please provide a small example that demonstrates your problem. A lot of helpful tips on how to do that can be [found here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: Have a look at [`scale_x_date`](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/scale_date.html).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Formatting dates with scale\_x\_date in ggplot2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10576095/formatting-dates-with-scale-x-date-in-ggplot2)

Answer (score 2):

You can change the scale in ggplot to datetime by using the function *scale_x_datetime*

```
mydata<-ggplot(data_plot,aes(x=Time,y=January)) + geom_line() +
      scale_x_datetime(date_breaks = "1 hour",
                       date_labels = "%I:%M %p")
```

Comment: Thanks very much Robert Plant. It worked. The time format it showed is 24 hr, is there any option to use 12 hr time system?