# ggplot2 does not accept breaks and lables with scale_x_continuous in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis-labels

I am trying to plot the SP500 Index near the 2004 Presidential Elections.

The data are:

```
Date        SP500
2004-05-01  1103
2004-06-01  1133
2004-07-01  1106
2004-08-01  1089
2004-09-01  1118
2004-10-01  1117
2004-11-01  1169
2004-12-01  1199
2005-01-01  1181
```

My code is the following:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)
library(lubridate)

ggplot(data_2004 , aes(x = Date, y = SP500)) +
  geom_path(color = "red", size = 2) + 
  theme_economist() +
  ggtitle("S&P 500 Index Tumbles because of US Presidential Elections") +
  ylab("SP500 Index") + 
  xlab("Date") + 
  scale_x_continuous(
    breaks = data_2004$Date,
    labels = c('5/2004', '6/2004', '7/2004','8/2004', '9/2004', '10/2004', 
               '11/2004', '12/2004', '1/2005'))
```

I get the following exception:

> ERROR while rich displaying an object: Error in
>   as.Date.numeric(value): 'origin' must be supplied

Comment: Make sure your date is of class `Date` and use `scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 month, date_labels = "%m/%Y")`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Formatting dates with scale_x_date in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10576095/formatting-dates-with-scale-x-date-in-ggplot2); [Formatting dates on X axis in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11748384/formatting-dates-on-x-axis-in-ggplot2)