# Replace month with year in x legend

Tags: r

How is it possible to receive a time line plot with multiple time lines in the same plot like this:

```
df3 <- structure(list(id = c(6L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 
                            4L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 
                            7L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 6L, 7L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 6L), month = c("2011-01", 
                                                                                       "2011-02", "2011-04", "2011-04", "2011-04", "2011-04", "2011-05", 
                                                                                       "2011-05", "2011-05", "2011-06", "2011-06", "2011-06", "2011-07", 
                                                                                       "2011-08", "2011-08", "2011-09", "2011-10", "2011-11", "2012-03", 
                                                                                       "2012-04", "2012-05", "2012-05", "2012-08", "2012-09", "2012-09", 
                                                                                       "2012-09", "2012-10", "2012-11", "2012-11", "2012-12", "2012-12", 
                                                                                       "2013-01", "2013-02", "2013-02", "2013-02"), frq = c(1, 
                                                                                                                                                  1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 
                                                                                                                                                  1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2)), row.names = c(NA, 35L
                                                                                                                                                  ), class = "data.frame")
```

Additionally how is it possible to add in the x legend the year evenif the plot frequency is per month? Also, in the group variable how is is possible two show exactly which is the variable and the color of the respective line?

What I tried is this

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df3,aes(x=month,y=frq,colour=id,group=id)) + geom_line()
```

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/q/10576095/3358272 resolve your question?

Comment: ... and you probably want to set to a Date format: `df3$date <- as.Date(paste(df3$month, "01", sep="-"))` and use that as the x-variable. And to show discrete colours your `id` variable should be a `factor`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
df3$id <- as.factor(df3$id)
ggplot(df3,aes(x=month,y=frq,colour=id,group=id)) + geom_line()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Function to read first (n)  characters:**

```
firstfew <- function(x, n){
x=as.character(x)
substr(x, 1, n)}

years=firstfew(df3$month,4)
df3$years=years

ggplot(df3,aes(x=month,y=frq,colour=id,group=id)) + geom_line()+ scale_x_discrete(labels= years)
```

**Facets view:**

```
ggplot(df3,aes(x=month,y=frq,colour=id,group=id)) + geom_line()+theme(legend.position="top",axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),axis.title.x=element_blank(),axis.text.x=element_blank(),panel.spacing.x=unit(0, "lines"),panel.grid.major = element_blank())+facet_wrap(~years,strip.position = "bottom",scales = "free_x")
```